# Invoking a Restful API via Azure Functions and Custom Handler

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I'm new to Azure Functions and Custom Handlers; so here's a newbie question.

Following the tutorial on this page (https://www.serverless360.com/blog/azure-function-custom-handlers#:%7E:text=Custom%20Handler%20is%20a%20feature%20in%20Azure%20Functions,not%20be%20a%20language%20supported%20by%20Azure%20functions), a simple web API application was created with the following controller:

```
namespace WebApplication.Controllers
{
    public class Book
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? Title { get; set; }
    }

    public class BooksController : Controller
    {
        [Route("books")]
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<List<Book>> GetBooks()
        {
            var books = new List<Book>();

            Book book1 = new Book();
            book1.Id = 1;
            book1.Title = "Title 1";
            books.Add(book1);

            Book book2 = new Book();
            book2.Id = 2;
            book2.Title = "Title 2";
            books.Add(book2);

            return books;
        }
    }
}
```

Using [dotnet dll-name],
[dotnet dll name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrLo7.png)

the controller responded accordingly:
[controller response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRY0V.png)

After configuring the Custom Handler via files **host.json**

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensionBundle": {
        "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
        "version": "[1.*, 3.0.0)"
    },
    "customHandler": {
        "description": {
            "defaultExecutablePath": "dotnet",
            "defaultWorkerPath": "..\\bin\\Debug\\net6.0\\WebApplication3.dll"
        }
    }
}
```

and **function.json**

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ]
}
```

as explained in the tutorial, Azure Functions Core Tools was invoked: func start
[func start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2wMM.png)

Using the provided URL, "books" was invoked, but nothing was displayed in the terminal, and the request failed in the browser with a 404 error:
[custom handler 404 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UESxQ.png)

A second route - api/HttpTrigger - was added to the controller:

```
[Route("books")]
[Route("api/HttpTrigger")]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<List<Book>> GetBooks()
{
```

which worked using [dotnet dll-name]
[new route works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0o25C.png)

but not when invoked using the Custom Handler:
[custom handler 500 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUdbF.png)

The request was displayed in the terminal though (very last line):
[custom handler terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2VzH.png)

Any thoughts about what the issue could be?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You use this host.json file.

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "customHandler": {
    "description": {
      "defaultExecutablePath": "app/WebApplication1",
      "arguments": [
        "--urls",
        "http://*:%FUNCTIONS_CUSTOMHANDLER_PORT%",
        "--TEST_VAR",
        "%TEST_VAR%"
      ]
    },
    "enableForwardingHttpRequest": true
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

More information and Source code on [Github](https://github.com/jplane/azure-functions-custom-handler) by jplance.

Comment: Hello, PunitSharma. Thank you for your reply. After making the modifications in **host.json**, the following exception was raised when running "func start":  `Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

Comment: What modification did you make in the host.json file? Please share the file text.

Comment: {
 "version": "2.0",
 "customHandler": {
  "description": {
   "defaultExecutablePath": "..\\bin\\Debug\\net6.0\\WebApplication3.dll",
   "arguments": [
    "--urls",
    "http://*:%FUNCTIONS_CUSTOMHANDLER_PORT%",
    "--TEST_VAR",
    "%TEST_VAR%"
   ]
  },
  "enableForwardingHttpRequest": true
 }
}